# How to NOT cache 500 Internal Server Errors in Varnish

Tags: vcl, varnish

I can't figure out, for the life of me, how to get varnish to ignore caching of 500 internal server errors. Basically, if someone hits varnish and is returned a 500 internal server error, I want varnish to not cache that page (set a 0s ttl/grace period?). I'm using varnish 3.0.3 and here's my VCL. By default, I want to cache the pages for 30 days.

```
sub vcl_fetch {
    # Set 30-day TTL
    set beresp.ttl = 2592000 s;
    set beresp.grace = 15d; /* The max amount of time to keep object in cache */

    if (beresp.status == 301 || beresp.status == 302) {
            return (hit_for_pass);
    }

    # Serve pages from the cache should we get a sudden error and re-check in one minute
    if (beresp.status >= 500) {
      set beresp.grace = 1s;
      set beresp.ttl = 1s;
      return (hit_for_pass);
    }

    # Unset the "etag" header (suggested)
    unset beresp.http.etag;

    return(deliver);
}
```

So, in english: if a 500 internal server is returned... the X-CACHE should show a MISS. When I refresh the page, if it is still 500 internal server, then it should again show a MISS. If the page is successfully delivered, it should show a HIT.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By default Varnish will only cache the following status codes[1]:

- 200: OK
- 203: Non-Authoritative Information
- 300: Multiple Choices
- 301: Moved Permanently
- 302: Moved Temporarily
- 307: Temporary Redirect
- 410: Gone
- 404: Not Found

Note that the first time the page is successfully delivered you will still get a MISS

[1] http://book.varnish-software.com/3.0/VCL_Basics.html#the-initial-value-of-beresp-ttl

Comment: Hm ... I do not understand why Varnish would cache the 404 error. We have been burned by this - the resource is back up but the user does not see it.

Comment: @Leonid, The 404 is generally cached by reverse proxies as it does not indicate an upstream server malfunctioning: rather the request was received and handled correctly, but the requested resource does not exist.

Comment: @NITEMAN This is not true at least for Varnish 4 on. See: https://github.com/mattiasgeniar/varnish-4.0-configuration-templates/issues/24

Comment: @Mohsen Note that I was refering to Varnish default behaviour (overrideable), name it [builtin.vcl](https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/master/bin/varnishd/builtin.vcl), and it's still true today: https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/master/doc/sphinx/users-guide/vcl-built-in-subs.rst#berespttl--berespgrace--berespkeep